# Caprover php fpm 502 issue

Tags: php, docker, caprover

I'm using [CapRover](https://caprover.com) in my VDS (virtual dedicated server) and I want to deploy my Laravel application. When I run the CapRover deploy command there is no problem with deployment. Also, the PHP Artisan migrate command is running, my tables created successfully, but when I go to the URL, CapRover return NGINX 502 Error.

here my Dockerfile:

```
ARG PHP_VERSION=${PHP_VERSION:-8.2}
FROM php:8.2-fpm-alpine AS php-system-setup

# Install system dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache dcron busybox-suid libcap curl zip unzip git
RUN apk add --update nodejs npm

# Install PHP extensions
COPY --from=mlocati/php-extension-installer /usr/bin/install-php-extensions /usr/bin/
RUN install-php-extensions intl bcmath gd pdo_mysql opcache redis uuid exif pcntl zip

# Install supervisord implementation
COPY --from=ochinchina/supervisord:latest /usr/local/bin/supervisord /usr/local/bin/supervisord

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

FROM php-system-setup AS app-setup

# Set working directory
ENV LARAVEL_PATH=/srv/app
WORKDIR $LARAVEL_PATH
COPY ./ /srv/app
RUN composer install --ignore-platform-reqs --prefer-dist --no-scripts --no-dev --no-autoloader
RUN npm install

RUN chmod 777 -R $LARAVEL_PATH

# Copy app
#COPY --chown=$NON_ROOT_USER:$NON_ROOT_GROUP . $LARAVEL_PATH/
COPY ./.deploy/config/php/local.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/local.ini

COPY ./.deploy/entrypoint.sh /

ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/entrypoint.sh"]

# Start app
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
EXPOSE 8000
```

./.deploy/config/php/local.ini

```
memory_limit = 512M
max_execution_time = 30
upload_max_filesize = 30M
post_max_size = 35M
```

./.deploy/entrypoint.sh

```
composer dump-autoload --no-interaction --no-dev --optimize
php artisan migrate --no-interaction --force
```